# UIViews ending up beneath tab bar

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, autolayout

In my app, I aligned a label the standard amount from the bottomLayoutGuide using autolayout. When the app first starts everything is layed out as I wanted but when I switch tabs and go back the label has disappeared under the tab bar controller.

If I rotate the device, the landscape view appears correctly and when I rotate it back to portrait the view is back to normal. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this behavior. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you do this in code or in a StoryBoard?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This happens due to a bug in iOS7, where the bottom layout guide is incorrectly set to height 0 instead of the tab bar's height. When you rotate the device, the bottom layout guide is set correctly.

Currently, your best option is to disable bottom extended layout:

```
- (UIRectEdge)edgesForExtendedLayout
{
    return [super edgesForExtendedLayout] ^ UIRectEdgeBottom;
}
```

Do this for each view controller that is displayed from the tab bar controller. Remember to set the tab bar view controller's background color to whatever suits your application.

Make sure to open a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com

To elaborate a little more, it seems `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called twice when switching view controllers. First time, everything is set correctly, but the second time bottom layout guide height is 0. You can see from the stack trace that the first one comes from tab bar layout, while the second call is from a scheduled CALayer layout, which is incorrect.

Comment: I have the same issue on iOS8. But when I implement the solution and disable bottom extended layout, if I change the orientation, or exit the viewcontroller and enter it again, the bottom extended layout actually will be the right size og the tabbar height.

Comment: Yup, this bug is still there in iOS 8.2.  Rotating the device to landscape, then back to portrait, fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm on iOS 8.3 and the bug still exists.

Comment: Guys, make sure to open a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I'm on 9.3 and bug still appears

Answer (score 15):

While Leo's answer shows how to do it programmatically, if you want to do this from the interface builder, select your View Controller and uncheck "Under bottom bars" from the Extend Edges section:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Calling setNeedsLayout is all that needs to be done. This essentially patches the framework bug. It needs to be called on the UITabBarController view itself when a new view is selected. Create a delegate for the app's tab bar controller. and put this in the delegate object:

```
@interface MyPatch : NSObject <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation MyPatch

-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [tabBarController.view setNeedsLayout];
}

@end
```

And initialize it wherever you want... something like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
         MyPatch *patch;

}

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    patch=[MyPatch new];
    myTabBarController.delegate=patch;
}

@end
```

Comment: This solution in my opinion in the best one. Choosing to not extend the view under the tab bar as suggested by @Steve results in the loss of the transparency effects. The layout pass mentioned by @Ben can be triggered directly in the view controller contained in the tab with no delegate needed. The tab bar controller is an optional property so you can call `tabBarController.setNeedsLayout()` followed by`view.layoutIfNeeded()` on the view controller's own view. This solved the issue for me in iOS 9

Answer (score 0):

Leo is right, the bottomLayoutGuide is returned incorrectly.
But unsetting the *extend edges under bottom bars* (or overriding `edgesForExtendedLayout`) had too much undesired effects on other subviews for me.

If you want to change only the constraint for one view according to the bottom layout guide,
implement `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and check the value of the `bottomLayoutGuide` property and adapt that one constraint if required, like so:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [self adaptBottomLayoutGuides];
}

/// Workaround for iOS7 bug returning wrong bottomLayoutGuide length if this is 1st tab in TabViewController
- (void)adaptBottomLayoutGuides {
    NSLog(@"%f", self.bottomLayoutGuide.length);

    CGFloat expectedHeight = 123;
    CGFloat adaptedSpacing = expectedHeight - self.bottomLayoutGuide.length;
    self.viewBottomLayoutSpacingConstrain.constant = adaptedSpacing;
}
```