# iOS UI elements are stretched after switching back and forth in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have several UI elements on an iOS app first view in a three view tab bar controller.

When I run the app, the first view looks a certain way but then I switch to another view and then back to the first one - the first one is stretched (mainly seems to be doing so vertically).

I presume it has something to do with constraints but I'm not sure.

What might be causing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide some code if you want help. There is not enough info here. That said, I would wager a bet that the issue is somewhere in your `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` methods.

Comment: I now notice 2 things:
1. It happens only on iPhone5 (not earlier).
2. If I open the address book or the contacts (functions I need in my app), I see the view stretching back to its default size. Then again stretches as I switch tabs.

Comment: could it be that the bottom layout guide is not constant when using iOS7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in iOS where the bottomLayoutGuide is wrongly set to 0.

[UIViews ending up beneath tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440197/uiviews-ending-up-beneath-tab-bar)

Answer (score 1):

When you see things change on you randomly that typically means you have an ambiguous layout.  Which means you did not give enough information to auto layout to know exactly what you want.  For example did you setup your horizontal constraints?

You can check this by setting a break point and running this in the debugger

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

Also if you post your constraints someone may be able to help you out better.

Comment: I've cleared any ambiguous layout.
It is just very unclear why the UIViewImage does not stay attached to the top and bottom layout guides.

Comment: Is it still acting weird after clearing the ambiguous layout?  It's really hard to answer your question with no details. Post your code and autolayoutTrace and maybe someone can help you out.

Comment: I have the trace, but what should I be looking for?

Comment: Can't I constrain an image to the "Bottom Layout Guide"? I am trying to have a background not obscured by the bottom bar, but automatically fixing the auto layout removes this constraint. It doesn't even show as ambiguous in the warnings.

Comment: Apparently the self.bottomLayoutGuide.length changes to 0 when I switch bask from other tab bar items and does not happen when I go back from the address book or contacts views.
What would cause this?